# Error While Adding DataSource in Data Connections

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

When I tried to add a connection it is showing the following error as shown in the attachment. “Unable to open the physical file. Access is Denied” .

When I searched about it, it suggest for adding the SQL Server’s account to the folder. Then, using the following query I found that the account is “LocalSystem”. When I tried to add  “LocalSystem” to ACL of the folder, such an account is not available. How do we resolve it and add the connection to DBML?

Note: When I used DataReader with the database name in a C# program, it worked well.

[image]

Query  Used:

```
declare @sqlser varchar(20)

EXEC master..xp_regread @rootkey='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
@key='SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQLSERVER',

@value_name='objectname', @value=@sqlser OUTPUT


SELECT convert(varchar(30),@sqlser)
```

[image]

Working C# Program:

```
    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        SqlConnection con = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;

        try
        {
            // Open connection to the database
            string ConnectionString = "server=D088DTRV;integrated security=true; database=BankAccount";

            con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            con.Open();


            string CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Account";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText);
            cmd.Connection = con;


            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                string test = rdr["AccountType"].ToString(); 
            }


        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `sysinternals` to figure out if the file is in use by another process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to Data Connections.

In the advanced window, when I checked, it was trying for ./SQLExpress. I modified it with ".".

I restarted the machine. I also stopped the SQLExpress in the services.msc

```
 Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=C:\DevTEST\Databases\LibraryReservationSystem.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```